# Elixir Ecto: How to write a migration with belongs_to and has_many?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two [models](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models), `Person`and `Pet`, and I want a `Person`to be able to [have many](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) pets, but a `Pet`to [belong to](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3) only one person:

```
defmodule MyApp.Person do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  alias MyApp.Pet

  schema "persons" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :pets, Pet
    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

and

```
defmodule MyApp.Pet do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  alias MyApp.Person

  schema "pets" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :person, Person
    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

So, how do I write a [migration](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html) for that?

```
defmodule Iloveproblems.Repo.Migrations.CreatePersonsAndPets do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:persons) do
      add :name, :string
      # I don't know :( . The has_many stuff
      timestamps()
    end

    create table(:pets) do
      add :name, :string
      # I don't know :( . The belongs_to stuff
      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `add :person_id, references(:persons), null: false` and so on as one way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess I will just move my comment here.

In order to create a field that is used as a foreign key, you can write something like this:

```
add :person_id, references(:persons), null: false
```

This ensures that the field is not null ( not always necessary ) and that it doesn't break referential integrity.